# Finding the second smallest integer in array

Tags: java, arrays

We are required in our assignment to find the second smallest integer in one array recursively. However, for the sake of understanding the subject more, I want to do it iteratively first (with the help of this website) and recursively on my own.

Unfortunately, doing it iteratively is quite confusing. I understand that the solution is simple but i can't wrap my head around it.

Below is my code, so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] elements  = {0 , 2 , 10 , 3, -3 }; 
    int smallest = 0; 
    int secondSmallest = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements.length; j++)
        {
            if (elements[i] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = elements[i];

                if (elements[j] < secondSmallest)
                {
                    secondSmallest = elements[j];
                }
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("The smallest element is: " + smallest + "\n"+  "The second smallest element is: " + secondSmallest);
}
```

This works for a few numbers, but not all. The numbers change around because the inner if condition isn't as efficient as the outer if condition.

Array rearrangements are forbidden.

Comment: You shouldn't initialize `smallest` with `0` if the array might contain only numbers greater than that. Try `int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE` for a start. Same goes for `secondSmallest`.

Comment: Alternatively, `elements[0]` is a suitable initialization for `smallest` and `secondSmallest`, since that is a candidate for the smallest in the array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this one. Second condition is used to catch an event when the smallest number is the first

```
    int[] elements = {-5, -4, 0, 2, 10, 3, -3};
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int secondSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i]==smallest){
          secondSmallest=smallest;
        } else if (elements[i] < smallest) {
            secondSmallest = smallest;
            smallest = elements[i];
        } else if (elements[i] < secondSmallest) {
            secondSmallest = elements[i];
        }

    }
```

**UPD** by @Axel

```
int[] elements = {-5, -4, 0, 2, 10, 3, -3};
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int secondSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i] < smallest) {
        secondSmallest = smallest;
        smallest = elements[i];
    } else if (elements[i] < secondSmallest) {
        secondSmallest = elements[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result when two numbers have the smallest value? For example when `int[] elements = {-5, -4, 0, 2, 10, 3, -5}`? Should it be `-5` or `-4`? This one gives you `-4`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to use `=>` instead of  `>` in the second `if`? (Oh, sorry, now it's the third.)

Comment: So better just remove the first `if`and the whole `&& elements[i] > smallest` to make it more readable.

Comment: For the input int[] elements = {-5, -4, 0, 2, 10, 3, -5} we should get -4 as second smallest number. In that case    else if (elements[i] < secondSmallest && elements[i] != smallest) {
            secondSmallest = elements[i];
        }

Comment: what if array has only sigle value? int [] arr = {0}, then it fails, returns the Max_VALUE

Comment: Why do you think it will fail? The task above doesn't state that second smallest should have any specific value in case of its absence. Thus your expectation is beyond the task definition

Comment: For `int[] elements = { 0, 0 };` I would return the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when array starts with first smallest number
scenario: arr = {1, 50, 30, 60, 25, 6, 13, 40}
add extra else if block like below




 `else if (smallest == secondSmallest) {
               secondSmallest = elements[i];
           }`

Answer (score 3):

**Here is TimeComlexity Linear O(N):**

```
  public static int secondSmallest(int[] arr) {
    if(arr==null || arr.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input array too small");
    }

    //implement
    int firstSmall = -1;
    int secondSmall = -1;

    //traverse to find 1st small integer on array
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)
        if (firstSmall == -1 || arr[firstSmall]>arr[i])
            firstSmall = i;

     //traverse to array find 2 integer, and skip first small
    for (int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if (i != firstSmall && (secondSmall == -1 || arr[secondSmall] > arr[i]))
            secondSmall = i;
    }

    return arr[secondSmall];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    int[] arr = { 4, 1, 2, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0 };

    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int smaller = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int i = 0;

    if (arr.length > 2) {
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i] < smallest) {
                smaller = smallest;
                smallest = arr[i];
            } else if (arr[i] < smaller && arr[i] > smallest) {
                smaller = arr[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Smallest number is " + smallest);
        System.out.println("Smaller number is " + smaller);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid array !");
    }
}
```

Comment: what if array has only sigle value? int [] arr = {0}, then it fails, returns the Max_VALUE

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in O(n) time. Below is the python code

```
def second_small(A):
    if len(A)<2:
        print 'Invalid Array...'
        return
    small = A[0]
    second_small = [1]
    if small >  A[1]:
        second_small,small = A[0],A[1]

    for i in range(2,len(A)):
        if A[i] < second_small and A[i]!=small:
            if A[i] < small:
                second_small = small
                small = A[i]
            else:
                second_small = A[i]
    print small, second_small
A = [12, 13, 1, 10, 34, 1]
second_small(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int findSecondSmallest(int[] elements) {
    if (elements == null || elements.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } 
    int smallest = elements[0]; 
    int secondSmallest = elements[0]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i] < smallest) {
            secondSmallest = smallest;
            smallest = elements[i];
        } 
        else if (elements[i] < secondSmallest) {
            secondSmallest = elements[i];
        }
    }
    return secondSmallest;
}
```

Comment: This code is not going to work if there is an element that is `>= smallest`, however `< secondSmallest`. In this case, `secondSmallest should be replaced.

Comment: Also if first value in elements is smallest, it won't set secondSmallest

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can do this

```
int[] arr = new int[]{34, 45, 21, 12, 54, 67, 15};
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

Comment: This is the shortest and the best solution, in my opinion but it is not recursive as described by the author of question ;)

Comment: Nope. It is wrong, if the 12 occurs more than once .

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] array = new int[]{10, 30, 15, 8, 20, 4};

        int min, secondMin;

        if (array[0] > array[1]){
            min = array[1];
            secondMin = array[0];
        }
        else{
            min = array[0];
            secondMin = array[1];
        }

        for (int i=2; i<array.length; i++){
            if (array[i] < min){
                secondMin = min;
                min = array[i];
            }
            else if ((array[i] > min) && (array[i] < secondMin)){
                secondMin = array[i];
            }
        }
       System.out.println(secondMin);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function in javascript

```
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers){  
  numbers = numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a - b; });
  return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
};
```

by providing a `compareFunction` for the sort functionality array elements are sorted according to the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int array[]= {-5, -4, 0, 2, 10, 3, -3};
        int min;
        int second_min;
        if(array[0]<array[1]){
            min=array[0];
            second_min=array[1];
        }else{
            min=array[1];
            second_min=array[0];
        }
        for(int i=2;i<array.length;i++){
            if(second_min > array[i] && min > array[i]){
                    second_min=min;
                    min=array[i];                              
            }else  if(second_min > array[i] && min < array[i]){
                min=min;
                second_min=array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(second_min);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Find the second minimum element of an array in Python, short and simple

```py
def second_minimum(arr):
    second = arr[1]
    first = arr[0]

    for n in arr:
        if n < first:
            first = n
        if n > first and n < second  :
            second = n

    return second

print(second_minimum([-2, 4, 5, -1, 2, 3, 0, -4, 1, 99, -6, -5, -19]))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
   int[] result = Arrays.asList(-3, 4,-1,-2).stream()
            .reduce(new int[]{Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE},
                    (maxValues, x) -> {
                        if (x > maxValues[0]) {
                            maxValues[1] = maxValues[0]; //max becomes second max
                            maxValues[0] = x;
                        }
                        else if (x > maxValues[1]) maxValues[1] = x;
                        return maxValues;
                    }
                    , (x, y) -> x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] elements  = {-4 , 2 , 10 , -2, -3 }; 
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    int secondSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        if (smallest>elements[i])
            smallest=elements[i];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        if (secondSmallest>elements[i] && elements[i]>smallest)
            secondSmallest=elements[i];

    }

    System.out.println("The smallest element is: " + smallest + "\n"+  "The second smallest element is: " + secondSmallest);
}
```

Comment: this will work on arrays with duplicates as well ,, like int[] elements  = {-4 , -4 , -4 , -4, -3 };

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
First condition checks if both values are less than value in array.
Second condition if value is less than small than `smallest=element[i]`
else `secondSmallest=elements[i]`..

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] elements  = {0 , 2 , 10 , 3, -3 }; 
    int smallest = elements[0];
    int secondSmallest = 0; 

      for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            if (elements[i]<smallest || elements[i]<secondSmallest )
            {
                if (elements[i] < smallest )
                {
                    secondSmallest  = smallest ;
                    smallest = elements[i];

                }
                else
                {
                    secondSmallest = elements[i];

                }
            }
        }

    System.out.println("The smallest element is: " + smallest + "\n"+  "The second smallest element is: " + secondSmallest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter array size = ");
    int size=in.nextInt();
    int[] n = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Enter "+ size +" values ");

    for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
        n[i] = in.nextInt();
    int small=n[0],ssmall=n[0];

    // finding small and second small
    for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++){
        if(small>n[i]){
            ssmall=small;
            small=n[i];
            }else if(ssmall>n[i])
                ssmall=n[i];
    }

    // finding second small if first element itself small
    if(small==n[0]){
        ssmall=n[1];
        for(int i=1;i<n.length;i++){
            if(ssmall>n[i]){
                ssmall=n[i];
                }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Small "+ small+" sSmall "+ ssmall);

    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int arr[] = {6,1,37,-4,12,46,5,64,21,2,-4,-3};
    int lowest =arr[0];
    int sec_lowest =arr[0];
    for(int n : arr){
        if (lowest >  n)
        {
            sec_lowest = lowest;
            lowest = n;

        }
        else if (sec_lowest > n && lowest != n)
            sec_lowest = n;
    }

    System.out.println(lowest+"   "+sec_lowest);

    }
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
public class SecondSmallestNumberInArray 
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                int arr[] = { 99, 76, 47, 85, 929, 52, 48, 36, 66, 81, 9 };
                int smallest = arr[0];
                int secondSmallest = arr[0];

                System.out.println("The given array is:");
                boolean find = false;
                boolean flag = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
                }

                System.out.println("");

                while (flag) 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
                    {
                        if (arr[i] < smallest) 
                        {   
                            find = true;
                            secondSmallest = smallest;
                            smallest = arr[i];
                        } else if (arr[i] < secondSmallest) {   
                            find = true;
                            secondSmallest = arr[i];
                        }
                    }
                    if (find) {
                        System.out.println("\nSecond Smallest number is Array : ->  " + secondSmallest);
                        flag = false;
                    } else {
                        smallest = arr[1];
                        secondSmallest = arr[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    **Output is**

    D:\Java>java SecondSmallestNumberInArray

    The given array is:

    99  76  47  85  929  52  48  36  66  81  9

    Second Smallest number is Array : ->  36

    D:\Java>
```

Comment: explain it please

Comment: Muhammad Muazzam Dry Run this  code very simple step Need to check if else statement

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getSecondSmallest(int[] arr){
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int secondSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(smallest > arr[i]){
                secondSmallest = smallest;
                smallest = arr[i];
            }else if (secondSmallest > arr[i] && arr[i] != smallest){
            secondSmallest = arr[i];
        }
            System.out.println(i+" "+smallest+" "+secondSmallest);
        }
        return secondSmallest;
    }
```

Just gave it a try with some of the test cases and it worked. Please check if it is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, program gives solution for both lowest value and second lowest value of array.

Initialize min and second_min with first element of array.Find out the min value and compare it with second_min value . If it (second_min) is greater than current element of array and min value then the second_min value replace with current element of array.

In case arr[]={2,6,12,15,11,0,3} like this , temp variable used to store previous second_min value.

```
public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //test cases.
            int arr[]={6,12,1,11,0};
            //int arr[]={0,2,10,3,-3}; 
            //int arr[]={0,0,10,3,-3}; 
            //int arr[]={0,2 ,10, 3,-3}; 
            //int arr[]={12,13,1,10,34,1};
            //int arr[]={2,6,12,15,11,0,3};
            //int arr[]={2,6,12,15,1,0,3};
            //int arr[]={2,6,12,15};
            //int arr[]={0,1};
            //int arr[]={6,16};
            //int arr[]={12};
            //int arr[]={6,6,6,6,6,6};
            int position_min=0;
            int min=arr[0];int second_min=arr[0]; int temp=arr[0];
            if(arr.length==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Lowest value is "+arr[0]+"\n Array length should be greater than 1. ");
            }
            else if(arr.length==2)
            {
                if(arr[0]>arr[1])
                {
                    min=arr[1];
                    second_min=arr[0];
                    position_min=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    min=arr[0];
                    second_min=arr[1];
                    position_min=0;
                }
                System.out.println("Lowest value is "+min+"\nSecond lowest value is "+second_min);
            }
            else
            {
                for( int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
                {
                   if(min>arr[i])
                   {
                       min=arr[i];
                       position_min=i;
                   }
                }
                System.out.println("Lowest value is "+min);
                for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
                {
                    if(position_min==i)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                         if(second_min > min & second_min>arr[i])
                         {
                             temp=second_min;
                             second_min=arr[i];
                         }
                         else if(second_min == min )
                         {
                             second_min=arr[i];
                         }
                    }
                }

                if(second_min==min )
                {
                    second_min=temp;
                }
                //just for message if in case all elements are same in array.
                if(temp==min && second_min==min)
                {
                    System.out.println("There is no Second lowest element in array.");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("\nSecond lowest value is "+second_min);
                }

            }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift version that runs in linear time. Basically, find the smallest number. Then assign the 2nd minimum number as the largest value. Then loop through through the array and find a number greater than the smallest one but also smaller than the 2nd smallest found so far.

```
func findSecondMinimumElementLinear(in nums: [Int]) -> Int? {
    // If the size is less than 2, then returl nil.
    guard nums.count > 1 else { return nil }

    // First, convert it into a set to reduce duplicates.
    let uniqueNums = Array(Set(nums))

    // There is no point in sorting if all the elements were the same since it will only leave 1 element
    // after the set removed duplicates.
    if uniqueNums.count == 1 { return nil }

    let min: Int = uniqueNums.min() ?? 0 // O(n)
    var secondMinNum: Int = uniqueNums.max() ?? 0 // O(n)
    // O(n)
    for num in uniqueNums {
        if num > min && num < secondMinNum {
            secondMinNum = num
        }
    }

    return secondMinNum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*a straight forward solution in lambda*

```
int[] first = {Integer.MAX_VALUE};
int rslt = IntStream.of( elements ).sorted().dropWhile( n -> {
    boolean b = n == first[0] || first[0] == Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    first[0] = n;
    return( b );
} ).findFirst().orElse( Integer.MAX_VALUE );
```

the returned `OptionalInt` from `findFirst()` can be used to handle the special cases
for `elements.length < 2` or `elements` containing only one value several times
*here* `Integer.MAX_VALUE` *is returned, if there is no second smallest integer*

Answer (score 0):

Well, that should work for you:

```js
function getSecondMin(array){
  if(array.length < 2) return NaN;

  let min = Math.min(array[0],array[1]);
  let secondMin = Math.max(array[0],array[1])

  for (let i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(array[i]< min){
        secondMin = min
        min = array[i]
      }
      else if(array[i] < secondMin){
        secondMin = array[i]
      }    
  }
  return secondMin;
}

const secondMin = getSecondMin([1,4,3,100,2])
console.log(secondMin || "invalid array length");
```